# appendContent can't be used in a Shiny render call

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, htmltools

The funciton `addSearchGoogle` from `leaflet.extras` is throwing this error in a Shiny-app:

> Warning in renderWidget(instance) :   Ignoring appended content;
> appendContent can't be used in a Shiny render call

The problem is this line:
https://github.com/trafficonese/leaflet.extras/blob/master/R/search.R#L210

Somehow it is not possible to use this function `htmlwidgets::appendContent` anymore.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? What is the new way of doing that or is that strictly forbidden now?

I tried something like this:

```
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies,
                        leafletSearchDependencies(),
                        list(htmltools::htmlDependency(
                          "googlesearchapi", "0.0.1",
                          src = c(href = url),
                          script = "js?v=3",
                          all_files = FALSE
                        )))
```

But then in the browser Console i am getting warnings that "google" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

htmltools::htmlDependency is the right approach and works as expected.
The script gets appended to the end of the head tag.

The bug in the repo must be from somewhere else.